# Properties of $\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)^{s}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Is this function $$\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)^{s}},\,Re(s)>1$$ well known? In particular I'm interessed about analytic continuation and its zeros and poles. Have this function the same properties of the Riemann Zeta function? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formally,$$\zeta\left(s\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{s}}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2k\right)^{s}}+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)^{s}}=\frac{1}{2^{s}}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{s}}+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)^{s}}$$
 whence$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)^{s}}=\zeta\left(s\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s}}\right).$$

Comment: Great! Just a typo, in the second line is $$\underset{n\geq1}{\sum}\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)^{s}}$$ right?

Comment: Uncountable improved my answer : I think all is ok now!

Answer (score 1):

Logger the function is well--known: it is the Dirichlet L-function modulo $2$. It is not primitive since $\phi(2)=1$ so it must be induced by the classical zeta function.